# script/rails was not found, when running rails server (Rails 4)?

Tags: ruby, ide, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

I'm getting this error in RubyMine when I try to start the server in debugging mode.

```
5:36:02 AM Error running Development: depot: Rails server launcher '/Users/eka/dev/tutorials/agile-rails-dev/depot/script/rails' wasn't found in project
```

My Rubymine version is 5.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is fixed on the master branch, and most likely the fix will be available in 5.X EAP during the next couple of weeks.

A quick workaround is:

> You can copy **"rails"** script from **"bin"** to **"script"** folder as a workaround.
>   NOTE: if u don't have "script" folder under your project root then please create new folder and name it as "script"(For Rails 4). Then copy "rails" from "bin" folder to it.

Credit goes to community support(Dennis Ushako)

Reference: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-13234

Comment: You need to give credit for the source of your quote. Failing to do so is a really bad thing on Stack Overflow. Also, quote the source verbatim, without marking it up.

Comment: Reference added @Tin Man